# why is vb storing wrong data in text file

Tags: vb.net

Hello everyone I want to write some data from an array into a text file and I am having trouble doing it. My code bellow

code where i create and store data into the studentArray

```
Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT As Integer = 6 'max amount of students
Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT_SCORES As Integer = 5 'max amount of scores

'Structure for student data
Public Structure StudentData
    Dim strStudentName As String 'to hold the student name
    Dim dblTestScoreArr() As Double ' Array to hold the test scores
    ' Dim dblAverage As Double 'to hold the average
End Structure



Dim StudentsArray(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT) As StudentData

'Stores the students names into array
Public Sub StudentNameData()
    StudentsArray(0).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent1.Text
    StudentsArray(1).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent2.Text
    StudentsArray(2).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent3.Text
    StudentsArray(3).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent4.Text
    StudentsArray(4).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent5.Text
    StudentsArray(5).strStudentName = Exercise3.txtNameStudent6.Text
End Sub
```

My approach to create the file

```
Sub SaveFile()
    Dim outputFile As StreamWriter 'Object variables
    Dim strFilename As String


    strFilename = InputBox("Enter the filename.")
    Try
        'Create Object the file 
        outputFile = File.CreateText(strFilename)
        For Each obj As StudentData In StudentsArray
            outputFile.WriteLine(obj)
        Next
        outputFile.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

What is being store in the file
    Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData
    Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData
     Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData
     Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData
     Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData
     Lab_9.StudentTestScoreModule+StudentData

Comment: "why is vb storing wrong data in text file" - Short answer:  Because you told it to.  Longer answer:  `StudentData` is a `Struct`, so when you write it to the file the `ToString()` method is called, and the default behavior for `ToString()` is the type of the object.  Either override `ToString` or write the structure's *fields* to your file.

Comment: @tim - because you told it too!

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean  as I am a beginner I try this way to and nothing got written to the file Sub SaveFile()
        Dim outputFile As StreamWriter 'Object variables
        Dim strFilename As String
        

        
       
            For Each obj As StudentData In StudentsArray
                outputFile.WriteLine(obj.strStudentName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(obj.dblTestScoreArr)
            Next

Comment: @PedroIt - Did you run it?  At a glance that code should work.

Comment: Did run It created a blank text file

Comment: If your file is empty then your array was empty. You either have a *scoping* issue where you fill it in in one place and it references a different instance in another place or.. you have your code (that we can not see) in the wrong order and you are writing before you fill the array in.

Comment: Try stepping through your code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Ok so I did some modification following your advice, this is what I am storing now Kim
System.Double[]
Paul
System.Double[]
Jay
System.Double[]
Carlos
System.Double[]
Mark
System.Double[]
Tim
System.Double[]

System.Double[]    None of the double values are being store, I haved look this over and over and I can't see why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a background:

First things first, when you create an array, the number you pass as parameter is not the total of elements of the array, but its **upper bound**. So, your array actually has 7 positions (from 0 to 6).

Now, `StreamWriter.WriteLine` receives a `string` as a parameter. When you pass something that's not a string, it tries to convert it using the `.ToString()` method every class and struct has (inherited from the allmighty `object` class). Now, the default behavior of the `.ToString()` method is to return the full name of the type of that variable. You can, however, override it to specify what you want it to return.

So, if you add in your structure

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() as string
    'Put here what you want to write on the file e.g. return "Hello World"
End Function
```

and run your original code, the file will have whatever you returned in the `ToString` method of the structure (in the example, it will put "Hello World" 6 times, one for every member of the array).

As for your second approach (the one with the StreamWriter) two things: the file is blank probably because you never flushed nor closed the stream after the `for each` loop; and you are having the same problem as the first code with `outputFile.WriteLine(obj.dblTestScoreArr)`: you are printing the result of the `Array.ToString()` function, wich will be `System.Array`. You have to print one of the values of the array, or all of them one by one.